# How to append strings in an array using C# or LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have a string `SelectedPath` which is combined with the `/` character. I have split the string using the `/` character and stored it in a string array as mentioned below.

```
string SelectedPath = "Users/Shangai/China/server";
string[] OUs = SelectedPath.Split('/').Reverse().ToArray();
string container = "";
        for(int i=0; i<OUs.Length;i++)
        {
            container +="OU="+OUs[i].ToString()+",";
        }
```

Result:

```
container="OU=Users,OU=SanFracisco,OU=Americas,OU=server.local,"
```

I want the above `container` value in the below-mentioned format.

```
container="OU=Users,OU=Newyork,OU=Americas,DC=server"
```

Note: The last array value has to add prefix with `DC=` not `OU=`.

How can I append this string in the aforementioned format. If we can do this with LINQ, it's really appreciated. Please suggest me something to achieve this. Also Is there any possible to do this by LINQ or Lambda expressions? If so, advise me on the same.

Comment: What is the value of `OUSelectedNodePath` ? Why you have `SelectedPath` in the code if it is not used anywhere ?

Comment: I have edited my code. Its SelectedPath only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Take` and `Last` to grab all but the last item, and then add on the last item. `String.Join` can then turn the array into a string with the desired separator. I didn't bother checking for `length >= 2` here, but you can handle that if needed.

```
string container = string.Format(
    "OU={0},DC={1}", 
    string.Join(",OU=", OUs.Take(OUs.Count() - 1)), 
    OUs.Last());
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
string SelectedPath = "Users/Shangai/China/server ";
string[] OUs = SelectedPath.Split('/');
string container = string.Join(",", OUs.Select((s, i) => (i == OUs.Length - 1 ? "DC=" : "OU=") + s));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string container = "OU=" + string.Join(",OU=", OUs.Take(OUs.Length - 1));
container += ",DC=" + OUs.Last();
```

Comment: @elgonzo, why ??? this will change the output, and I don't think it is required like that.

Comment: @Downvoter, could you please point to the mistake in answer ?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but your example code still misses the first 'OU=' (string.Join just puts ",OU=" **between** the elements, but not in front of the first element).

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the first part of your list you need to do the following:

```
var firstPart = ous.Take(ous.Count - 1);
```

and your last element is

```
var lastElement = ous.Last();
```

So to prepend `"OU="` is easy enough:

```
var firstPartPrepended = firstPart.Select(x => "OU=" + x);
```

and finally

```
var complete = String.Join("," firstPartPrepended) + ",DC=" + lastElement;
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your `for` loop like this :

```
for(int i=0; i < OUs.Length - 1; i++)
{ 
    container += string.Format("OU= {0},", OUs[i]);
}

container += string.Format("DC= {0}", OUs[OUs.Length - 1]);
```

Simply iterate over until the last item.Then append the `DC=` prefix after the loop.I prefer the simplest solution in this case, instead of creating unnecessary enumerators more than once without no reason, use `LINQ` when it's really helpful and necessary, otherwise you will not lose anything using a simple loop.